# Given a progression 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3... What will be An?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, arithmetic-progressions

I came up with this in mind and couldn't find a way to solve it. With this progression:
$$
A_0 = 0,\\
A_1 = 1,\\
A_2 = 1,\\
A_3 = 2,\\
A_4 = 2,\\
A_5 = 2,\\
...\\
A_N
$$
for the step $k$ of the sequence, there will be $k$ times the number $k-1$.

(Example for the 4th part of the sequence, there will be $4$ times the number $3$ like this: $3, 3, 3, 3$)

What will be $A_n$ for a given $n$? Why?
What are these kind of progressions called?

Comment: This is related to the [triangle numbers](https://oeis.org/A000217) and its inverse sequence.  $T_0=0, T_1=1, T_2=3, T_3=6,\dots,T_n$ can be interpreted as "*the position of the first time you see the number $n$ in your sequence*"  One has $T_n = n(n+1)/2$, so if you go through the effort of finding the functional inverse of the related real function $f(x)=x(x+1)/2$, and take the floor function, one gets $A_n = \lfloor(-1+\sqrt{8n+1})/2\rfloor$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears as https://oeis.org/A003056

As mentioned in comment above, one way to derive the formula for this is to recognize its relation to the [triangle numbers](https://oeis.org/A000217) and find the functional inverse to that sequence, throwing in the floor function to have it map solely to integer values, yielding the expression

$$A_n = \left\lfloor \frac{-1+\sqrt{8n+1}}{2}\right\rfloor$$

For more information, visit the link at the start.

Comment: I get it! The binomial function that generates the triangle numbers is $X = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. Solving for $X$ we get this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Notice $a_{\sum_{i=0}^k i=\frac {k (k+1)}2}=k $.

So $a_n=k: \frac {k (k+1)}2\le n <\frac {(k+1)(k+2)}2$

If that's not enough $k (k+1)/2=n $ means

$k^2+k-2n=0;k=\frac {-1 +\sqrt {1+8n}}{2}$

So $a_n =\lfloor \frac {-1 +\sqrt {1+8n}}{2} \rfloor $